# Formula rewriting software

Tags: math-software

I would like to have a program that rewrites formula's for me.

What I would like a software where I can imput some formulas, constraints, and so on,

and then the program outputs the formulas that result from them.

For example,

if I input

- $ i = \frac{1}{p} $
- $ c = \frac{i+p}{2} $
- $ d = \frac{1}{c} $
- $ r = |c-p| $

with all varables > 0, 0 < p < 1

The program can make:

- $ d = \frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+1}} $

Does such software exist?

(free if possible)

Comment: I suppose that a CAS would do it.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica can express $d$ in a number of ways.

```
Union[Cases[Reduce[
 i>0 && c>0 && d>0 && r>0 && 0<p<1 &&
  i==1/p && c==(i+p)/2 && d==1/c &&
  (r==i-p || r==p-i), #] & /@ Permutations[{i, p, c, d, r}],
 Equal[d, rhs_] :> Equal[d, Simplify[rhs, Assumptions -> r > 0]], 2]]
```

[image]

I suppose the last form is close to what you want.  The dependence of the variables in the result is dictated by the order of the variables in the call to `Reduce`.  I used `Permutations` to generate all the possibilities.  I suppose if we solve for $r$, then $d$, and then the rest, we should get something like what you want.

```
Reduce[i>0 && c>0 && d>0 && r>0 && 0<p<1 &&
  i==1/p && c==(i+p)/2 && d==1/c &&
  (r==i-p || r==p-i), {r,d,p,c,i}]
```

[image]

You can also use `Eliminate` and then call `Solve` on the result, though I don't think that this technique works easily with your inequality constraints.

```
Eliminate[i==1/p && c==(i+p)/2 && d==1/c && (r==i-p || r==p-i), {i,c,p}]
Solve[%, d]
```

[image]

The `Eliminate` based approach can also be done in the open source CAS [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/).

```
eliminate([i-1/p, c-(i+p)/2, d-1/c,r-(p-i)],[i,p,c]);
solve(%,d);
```

$$\left[ d=-{{2}\over{\sqrt{r^2+4}}} , d={{2}\over{\sqrt{r^2+4}}}\right]$$

I don't know that Maxima provides anything quite like Mathematica's `Reduce`, however.  Perhaps, someone will correct me.